# Step up 3.3V to 5V and draw 500mA without a voltage collapse/break down

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, 3.3v, step-up

I would like to step up 3.3V from my power supply with the help of a dc-dc-boost converter to 5V and then I want to draw 500mA by placing a 10 Ohm resistor between the output-pin of the boost-converter and ground.

The problem: The voltage drops down to 3.3V. (With 100 Ohm not)

Is there somewhere a module which can supply such a current draw? If yes, which one - sot-packages preffered?

[image]

I already tried those converters: MT3608, Pololu S7V8A and SX1308

Comment: Which boost converter did you use? What is the source providing the 3.3 V supply?

Comment: I tried already these converters: MT3608, Pololu S7V8A and SX1308 and I'm using a normal workbench power supply (RD6006)

Comment: What is the current limit on the 3.3 V supply?

Comment: @ThePhoton ja, ok, you caught me. I increase it and it worked. No, big voltage drop anymore. Thank you very very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a generic answer:

Your module has to be able to provide at least 500mA - however usually in engineering you have to account for certain safety margin - so if you need exactly 500mA output, the module should be able to provide more (how much is a different topic then your question, but still important to consider in your design).

So as a ballpark calculation Id calculate like this:

With Safety factor i: 1.5

P_out = I_out  * U_out * i = 0.5A * 5V * 1.5 = 3.75W

As you boost converter has only a certain efficiency the input power into it should be higher:
With a efficiency n_eff of 85% <- just a generic value as example, you should check the data of your module

P_in = P_Out / n_eff = 3.75W / 85% = 4.41W

Out of this input per you can calculate what supply is necessary for the module:

I_in = P_in / U_in = 4.41W / 3.3V = 1.34A

So if your 3.3V power supply can provide 1.34A and your module 0.75A / 3.75W, then you should not see the voltage stop with a static 10Ohm load resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to increase the current limit of the power supply since the mentioned modules are capable for such a current draw.